# Difference between regular objects and Strings

Tags: java, string, object, reference

```
public class StringHandling {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "Hello World";
    Test b = new Test(5);
    String c = a;
    Test d = b;
    System.out.println("String a = " + a);
    System.out.println("Test b = " + b.a); 
    System.out.println("String c = " + c);
    System.out.println("Test d = " + d.a);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    a = "Hello People";
    b.a = 15;

    System.out.println("String a = " + a);
    System.out.println("Test b = " + b.a); 
    System.out.println("String c = " + c);
    System.out.println("Test d = " + d.a);
 }
}
```

Output:
`a` and `c` is different and `b` and `d` is same why? Both `String` and `Test` are `Objects`.
Please Explain so me what is the difference between regular objects and Strings. Thanks you very much.

Comment: You are not doing the same operation on each so you can't expect the same outcome.

Comment: Please explain me. Thanks

Comment: What is the difference between `a = "Hello People"` and `b.a = 15`? Work that out and you'll have your answer. You'll learn much more than if we spoonfeed out.

Comment: Thanks Boris the Spider, I will be careful in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first `a` and `c` point to same String object. But then with assigment of

```
a = "Hello People"
```

`a` holds reference to another string object so as a result they're different.

Opposite happens for `Test` instance. They're still holding references to same object. So you basically changing the object's property with assigment of

```
b.a = 15
```

Answer (score 3):

> Output: a and c is different

You assigned 'c' and later changed 'a' so they are different.

> and b and d is same why?

You assigned `b` to `d` but you don't replace either so they are still pointing to the same object.

Comment: Okay so i created new String object when i changed `a`. Thanks.

Comment: @AbuBakkarSiddique It's worth remember that `a` is a *reference* not an `object` When you alter `a` you have changed the *reference* to an object, not altering the object itself.  When you assign `b.a = ` you are altering the object `b` refers to.